# API for Google Pay UPI to fetch transaction history

Tags: api, google-pay

I am trying to build a tool to track and create a heatmap of the expenses i am making on the Google Pay UPI app, i wanted to know if there is any API that can pull all the transactions and all the details about that transaction from the app .

I tried visting the google pay documentation but i couldn't really find any such API which could do that . I was thinking if there can be a simple HTTP GET command with authentication key which can simply give me the transaction history with probably the location of the transaction amount and basically everything related to it

Comment: singahl, have you got the solution?